# Conditional expectation of quadratic form

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am unsure if my derivation is correct. I want to derive an expression for $$\mathbb{E}[x^\top A x|y],$$
where x and y are random vectors and A is a constant matrix, which holds for all joint distributions of $(x,y)$ and is similar to 
$$
\mathbb{E}[x^\top A x] = \mathbb{E}[x^\top]A\mathbb{E}[x] + tr(A\mathbb{E}[(x- \mathbb{E}[x])(x - \mathbb{E}[x])^\top])
$$
whose derivation can be found here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48066/expected-value-of-quadratic-form .

I get:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[x^\top A x | y] &= \sum_i \sum_j a_{ij}\mathbb{E}[x_i x_j | y] \\
&= \sum_i\sum_j a_{ij}(\mathbb{E}[(x_i - \mathbb{E}[x_j])(x_j-\mathbb{E}[x_j])] + \mathbb{E}[x_i|y]\mathbb{E}[x_j] + \mathbb{E}[x_i]\mathbb{E}[x_j|y] -\mathbb{E}[x_i]\mathbb{E}[x_j]) \\
&= \mathbb{E}[x^\top|y]A\mathbb{E}[x] + \mathbb{E}[x^\top]A\mathbb{E}[x|y]-\mathbb{E}[x^\top]A\mathbb{E}[x]+tr(A\mathbb{E}[(x- \mathbb{E}[x])(x - \mathbb{E}[x])^\top])
\end{align}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditional expectations, variances and covariances generally share the same properties of their un-conditional counterparts: perhaps most notably played out through linearity of expectations.

In particular, we can derive the following statement which is analogous to the un-conditioned case

$$\text{Cov}(x_ix_j\, |\,y) = \mathbf E[ x_i x_j \, | \, y] - \mathbf E [x_i\, | \, y] \mathbf E[x_j\, | \, y ]$$

If we assume $x \in \mathbf R^n$, and denote $\nu = \left( \mathbf E[X_i \, | \, y]\right)_{i=1}^n$, and $\Theta = \left( \text{Cov}(x_i,x_j \, | \, y ) \right)_{i,j =1}^n$, analogously to how $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ are defined in the post you linked to above (and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48066/expected-value-of-quadratic-form)), then the proof follows exactly as before:

\begin{align*}
\mathbf E[x^T A x \, | \ y ] & = \sum_{i,j} a_{i,j} \mathbf E[x_ix_j \, | \, y] \\
& = \sum_{i,j} a_{i,j} \left( \Theta_{i,j} + \nu_{i} \nu_j\right) \\
& = \text{Tr}(A\Theta) + \nu^T A \nu,
\end{align*}
where in the final line we relied on the property that given square matrices $E,F$, we have that $\text{Tr}(EF) = \sum_{i,j} E_{ij}F_{ij}$.

Comment: I agree with you apart from the sign error which occurred when you substituted $\mathbb{E}[x_ix_j|y]$ (Please fix it and I will mark you answer as accepted). I went wrong by using the wrong definition of $Cov(x_ix_j|y)$. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for spotting that; corrected now.